# Does varchar without size specification slow down performance of SQLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, varchar

I'm using SQLITE for my Disk catalog project in c#. During testings i'm encountring length issues when using fixed size varchar. So i decided to keep varchar size unlimited while developing. Some times i have to read 40,000 rows in a table at once.

My question is can fixed size varchar increase the performance in sqlite?

Comment: To read: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite completely ignores any length restriction:

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html says:

> **2.2 Affinity Name Examples**
>
> Note that numeric arguments in parentheses that following the type
>   name (ex: "VARCHAR(255)") are ignored by SQLite - SQLite does not
>   impose any length restrictions (other than the large global
>   SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH limit) on the length of strings, BLOBs or numeric
>   values.

Comment: Good catch, i conducted tests on tables with same two columns and idetical 50,000 data entries but one have fixed size and other have only unlimited size. Results were similar. Query from fixed size table taken 420.17 milli seconds and unlimited size table taken 430.42 milli seconds. I conducted 12 tests on each table and taken average of it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes. It does increase performance a bit because it does not do any dynamic size allocations in case a rewrite occurs on the specific column.